# Fixnum to Array

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to take a Fixnum such as `4` and convert it to an ordered array like `[1, 2, 3, 4]`? I.e.,

```
x = 4
x.do_some_magic!
x # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: @sawa is correct this functionality is not possible in this context because the receiver is a `Fixnum` and cannot be mutated in such a fashion as to replace this referenced value with an `Array`. That being said I have not idea why no one suggested `Integer#upto` or `Integer#downto` e.g. `1.upto(4).to_a #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: @engineersmnky: `upto` is suggested in a deleted answer.

Comment: @Seal, I see you uncheked my answer - just curious if you no longer find my solution acceptable or you expect to see more answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible (despite the goal..):

```
x = 4
(1..x).to_a
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Or with method

```
def method_name
  (1..self).to_a
end

x.method_name
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: its funny you put this because right as I posted this question, the answer hit me!

Comment: This is not actually what the OP asked for. The OP wanted `x` to refer to the array.

Comment: @sawa probably the answer not being what OP asked is the reason he accepted it ;) Your point is good, but I am pretty sure OP did not mean to change `x` itself. If he did though, he is notified about your answer and is free to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Array#`new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-c-new) passing the size and a block like this:

```
size = 4
Array.new(size, &:next)
# => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This is possible because the block yields the index of each element and use what returns as its value. Examples:

```
Array.new(4) { |i| i }
# => [0, 1, 2, 3]
Array.new(4) { |i| i + 1 }
# => [1, 2, 3, 4]
Array.new(4) { |i| i.odd? }
# => [false, true, false, true]
```

Comment: While this produces the desired output, it shouldn't ever be used in any code that matters.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Can you explain?

Comment: Gladly. Production code should be written with readability in mind. It is not obvious at all what this line does. I'm willing to bet that 9 out of 10 ruby programmers won't predict the output without consulting Array documentation. `Range#to_a`, on the other hand, is widely used. One might be a little confused by differences between `a..b` and `a...b`, but overall it's quite obvious.

Comment: Also, this code is quite fragile. It relies on the fact that `0.next` produces `1`. A slightest change in requirements ("resulting array should be [2, 3, 4, 5]") will result in big code changes.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Sorry, but I don´t think it is so hard to know how initialize an array this way and as the requirement changes as you said, the range solution won´t work either. That said, I am updating my answer to explain what I am doing here.

Comment: In this concrete example, the range solution will need lesser changes (just change the boundaries). Easier to change code = better code. In a big legacy app you have much more important things to keep in memory than some rarely used array constructor. Anyhow, this piece of advice is probably out-of-place here. :)

Answer (score 1):

No. It is impossible. It is impossible to convert a fixnum into an array retaining its identity as a Ruby object. So in order to do what you wrote, the method `do_some_magic!` has to change the reference of a variable that originally referred to the receiver object (`x` in your example). However, a method works on a Ruby object, not on a variable, and there is no way for a method to know under what variable name the receiver had been accessed to. So it is impossible.

Comment: You are always so literal :)

Comment: The method wouldn't necessarily have to change the reference. It could also change the class. However, that is also impossible, so the end result is the same.